# How to remove an line from a numpy array/table if it is empty

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy arrays which are around 2000 long each, but not every element has a value. Some are blank. As you can see at the end of the code ive stacked them into one called 'match'. How would I remove a row in match if it is missing an element. So for example if a particular ID is missing the magnitude it removes the entire row. I'm only interested in keeping the rows that have data for all of the elements.

```
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np

data = '/home/myname/datable.fits'
data = Table.read(data, format="fits") 

ID = np.array(data['ID'])
ID.astype(str)

redshift = np.array(data['z'])
redshift.astype(float)

radius = np.array(data['r']) 
radius.astype(float)

mag = np.array(data['MAG'])
mag.astype(float)

match = (ID, redshift, radius, mag)
np.stack(match, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the numpy.isnan method which gives true for missing values and false for existing values. But numpy.isnan can be applied to NumPy arrays of native dtype (such as np.float64).

Your requirement can be achieved as follows:

Note: considering data is your numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(some_array) # set data as your numpy array
key_col = np.array(data[:,0], dtype=np.float64) # If you want to filter based on column 0
filtered_data = data[~np.isnan(key_col)] # ~ is the logical not here
```

For better flexibility, consider using pandas!!
Hope this helps!!